# redis py and hgetall - why key values have a b""?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

Below is the dict return from redis.  Why the b?  How do I get rid of it?

```
data = r_client.hgetall(key)
{b'test1:r': b'2', b'test2:f': b'2'}

print('test1:r' in data)
False

print(b'test1:r' in data)
True
```

When I get data from redis how do I get rid of that terrible b?

I mean I have do this to get what I want:

```
new_data = {}
for key,value in data.items():
    new_data[key.decode()] = value.decode()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: No does not solve.

Comment: It does solve one of your questions, but you are asking two: 1) What is the `b` character and 2) How do I avoid getting this `b` character from redis.

Comment: If you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273618/3890632) in the duplicate, it explains how to transform b-strings to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to decode the bytes of a string:

```
b'test1:r'.decode('utf-8')
```

decode all your keys:

```
data = {b'test1:r': b'2', b'test2:f': b'2'}
data= {key.decode('utf-8'):value for key,value in data.items()}
print('test1:r' in data) # True
print(b'test1:r' in data) # False
```

Answer (score 10):

You can add params to get rid of that.

```
client = redis.Redis('localhost', charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
```